# Heat and ionization energy loss for a nucleus

Tags: particle-physics

What are the energy loss magnitudes for heat and ionization? I’m interested for an argon nucleus in liquid argon with a kinetic energy of 1-100keV. There are others relevant energy loss mechanisms at those energies? What about Electrons?

Comment: One could use, say, SRIM to calculate the (average) nuclear and electronic energy losses...

Comment: Do you really need the energy loss broken down into terms representing ionization and non-ionizing heating? If not, then this is a well-studied problem, and there is open-source software to calculate it.